# Ошибка ValueError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день! 
При попытке ввести данный кусок кода :

```
for i in input() :
    s = int(i)
    print(s)
```

обнаружила, что он работает только при введении положительных целых чисел, но возникает ошибка, если вводишь отрицательное число (например, -3). Цикл for необходим, т.к. в программе стоит задача вводить числа до определенных пор (эти условия указаны в цикле while над тем куском кода, который я здесь привела).

Потом специально проверила, а не случилось ли что с моей клавиатурой и знаком минуса. Нет, все в порядке, такой код работает:

```
a = -3
print(int(a))
```

и выводит -3. Помогите, пожалуйста, я нуб, и совершенно не понимаю, почему так.

Comment: У вас проверка неправильная, ведь в `input` будет строка, поэтому: `print(int("-3"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, например, вы вводите `-3`, и в `input()` будет `"-3"`, после вы итерируете `"-3"` в цикле и первый символ в переменной `i` это `"-"`, понимаете?

Предполагаю, что вы вводите одно или несколько чисел, разделенных пробелом, тогда код будет примерно такой:

```
for i in input().split():
    n = int(i)
    print(n)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Правильно ли я теперь поняла, что i принимает поочередно все знаки в строке input? То есть если ввести for i in input() , и input будет ab3-1 , то i будет принимать поочередно значения a, b, 3, - и 1 ?

Comment: @Алена, вводите например: "-3 3 0 1 999", и после `input().split()` получите: ["-3", "3", "0", "1", "999"]. Список будет итерирован в цикле и в `i` будут последовательно появляться строки "-3", "3", "0"  и т.д.