# Как получить int значения с виджета Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500") 
main_menu = Menu()
a = set()
b = set()
с = set()



#Functions
def generate_set(elem):

    if elem == "A":
        a = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value1)))
    elif elem == "B":
        b = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value2)))   
    elif elem == "C":
        c = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value3)))      
def Window_open_2():
    Window2 = Tk()

def Window_open_3():
    Window3 = Tk()            
############################
root.config(menu = main_menu)
e1 = Label(text = "Бурбело Сергій Сергійович ІВ-91 Номер у списку 04")
e1.pack()

lab1 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 8 , y = 200)
Entry1 = Entry(root, width = 25)
Entry1.place(x = 10, y = 220)
value1 = Entry1.get()
bt1 = Button(text = "Згенерувати множину А ")
bt1.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("A"))
bt1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)

lab2 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 330 , y = 200)
Entry2 = Entry(root,width = 25)
Entry2.place(x = 330, y = 220)
value2 = Entry2.get()
bt2 = Button(text ="Згенерувати множину B ")
bt2.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("B"))
bt2.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 25)

lab3 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 170 , y = 280)
Entry3 = Entry(root, width = 25)
Entry3.place(x = 170, y = 300)
value3 = Entry3.get()
bt3 = Button(text = "Згенерувати множину C ")
bt3.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("C"))
bt3.place(x = 170, y = 320)
main_menu.add_cascade(label = 'Window 2', command = Window_open_2)
main_menu.add_cascade(label  = "Window 3", comman = Window_open_3)



root.mainloop()
```

Проблема:

```
def generate_set(elem):

    if elem == "A":
        a = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value1)))
    elif elem == "B":
        b = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value2)))   
    elif elem == "C":
        c = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value3)))
```

Ошибка:

> File "tk.py", line 16, in generate_set
>       a = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value1))) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663443/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 проблема:**

Вы получаете значения текстовых полей сразу после запуска программы, когда в них еще пусто. Пользователь просто не успеет к этому моменту ничего ввести. Поэтому из текстовых полей считывается пустая строка, которая конечно же не является числом, о чем и говорит ошибка. Значения из полей нужно считывать после нажатия на кнопки, в привязанных обработчиках нажатия.

**2 проблема:**

```
bt1.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("A"))
bt2.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("B"))
bt3.bind('<Button-1>', generate_set("C"))
```

в таких строках функция сразу вызывается, а в метод `bind` передается результат ее выполнения. Чтобы функция не выполнялась сразу, можно обернуть ее в лямбду:

```
bt1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: generate_set("A"))
```

Параметр `event` в данном случае нужен из-за того, что в обработчик события всегда передается параметр с описанием события.

**3 скорее совет, а не проблема:**

К кнопкам лучше привязываться через параметр `command`, а не через события. При привязке к событию клика мышью кнопка может вести себя не совсем нормально - "залипать" при клике, например. Также, при привязке через `command` аргумент `event` не передается.

**С учетом вышесказанного:**

```
from tkinter import *
import random 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500") 
main_menu = Menu()
a = set()
b = set()
с = set()


#Functions
def generate_set(elem):

    if elem == "A":
        value1 = Entry1.get()
        a = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value1)))
        print(a)  # выводим на консоль, чтобы видно было, что что-то происходит
    elif elem == "B":
        value2 = Entry2.get()
        b = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value2)))   
        print(b)
    elif elem == "C":
        value3 = Entry3.get()
        c = set(random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(int(value3)))      
        print(c)

############################
root.config(menu = main_menu)
e1 = Label(text = "Бурбело Сергій Сергійович ІВ-91 Номер у списку 04")
e1.pack()

lab1 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 8 , y = 200)
Entry1 = Entry(root, width = 25)
Entry1.place(x = 10, y = 220)

bt1 = Button(text = "Згенерувати множину А ", command=lambda: generate_set("A"))
bt1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)

lab2 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 330 , y = 200)
Entry2 = Entry(root,width = 25)
Entry2.place(x = 330, y = 220)

bt2 = Button(text ="Згенерувати множину B ", command=lambda: generate_set("B"))
bt2.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 25)

lab3 =Label(text = "Введіть кількість елементів:").place(x = 170 , y = 280)
Entry3 = Entry(root, width = 25)
Entry3.place(x = 170, y = 300)

bt3 = Button(text = "Згенерувати множину C ", command=lambda: generate_set("C"))
bt3.place(x = 170, y = 320)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого виджета попробуйте

```
int(Entry1.get())
int(Entry2.get())
int(Entry3.get())
```